# Multi Level / Hierarchical Time Series Models in Python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series

I have data with different leaders and their performance score over a period of time. I need to analyse this time series data where data for each leader should be considered different time series data. I tried Autoregression model but as per my research it doesn't have functionality to perform multi level analysis like in LMER.
Is there any way I can do the multilevel analysis on the time series data?